# Magento XML Layout: Forcing a block to go last

Tags: php, xml, magento, layout

In Magento XML layouts, is there a way of ensuring a block you are adding goes last?

I am aware of `before=""` and `after=""` for positioning a block relative to other blocks.

I was wondering if there was a way of forcing a block to be the last one rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `after="-"` everything  should work as you want.